# Javascript nested list css

Tags: javascript, css, mootools, nested-lists

I have a list below:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a>Link1</a>
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a>SubLink1</a>
         </li>
         ...   
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
      <a>Link2</a>
   </li>
   ...
</ul>
```

And would like to add `'css_class'` to the current mouseovered `<li>` element:

```
document.getElements('li').addEvents({
            mouseover: function(){      
               this.addClass('css_class');
            },
            mouseout: function(){
               this.removeClass('css_class');
            }
});
```

But this code is wrong as my parent`<li>` also has `'css_class'`.
How can I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: This is a mootools.net library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling up the listener tree:

```
document.getElements('li').addEvents({
  mouseover: function(e){
    this.addClass('css_class');   
    e.stopPropagation();
  },
  mouseout: function(){
    this.removeClass('css_class');   
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```